# When do we need to create service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

For example, I have some functions `fooA()`, `fooB()` ... which are used in many components.

Should I wrap these methods in a service class and inject them, or just export a class with these static functions?

Wrap in service:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
    fooA() {...}

    fooB() {...}
}

@Component({
    ...
    providers: [SampleService]
})
export class SampleComponent {
    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {...}

    method() {
        this.sampleService.fooA();
    }
}
```

Simply export a class:

```
export class Utils {
    static fooA() {...}

    static fooB() {...}
}

@Component({...})
export class SampleComponent {
    method() {
        Utils.fooA();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have methods which are reused , you should create a [`shared service`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understand-services-in-angular-2/). Or create a base component with those methods and extend your component from the **`base component`**.

Comment: Please see my updated code snippet. Sorry for I have not described my question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an angular service generally to share functionality among component **that are not necessarily with a parent-child relation or sibling components**. This way you can better encapsulate the functionality you want in one service and inject it in the component constructor where you want to use it.

For example, if you want to create an Async communication to share data between two component, you can create a service using **RxJS library**, and let component subscribe to messages that they want to get, or create subject to send data to other components.

You can read about some examples here:

[angular component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

[ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb)

For your example, instead of copying the functionality of `fooA()` and `fooB()` in each component, for better design and code encapsulation, you can create an angular service using the [`Injectable` decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable), and  inject that service in each component where you need to call those functions.

When you choose to export those functions, they will be available for use in every component, instead you can choose just to use them by injecting a service.

Comment: Please see my updated code snippet. Sorry for I have not described my question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use static functions when the logic for these functions are pretty much global and doesn't change across the application.

Creating a service with non-static functions suits when we want to use the functions inside the particular class i.e. private functions or when another class needs it i.e. public function. Also, if a class wants to override the implementation of the super class(a class which it inherits from) we define the function as a non-static member.

**If your logic is global and doesn't change across the application use them as static functions otherwise make them non-static members.**

Comment: OK, but why? What benefits between static functions and services?